# angularjs bind not working on dynamic template and recursive directive

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to apply dynamic templates to my recursive directive and it doesn't work properly; may be the incorrectly usage or not the best practice.

my directive:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
.directive("question", function (RecursionHelper, $http, $templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {question: '=' },
        templateUrl: 'views/activity.question.html',
        compile: function (element) {
            return RecursionHelper.compile(element, function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
                $http({ method: 'GET', url: './views/answer-types/answer.' + scope.question.AnswerType + '.html', cache: true }).then(function (result) {
                    iElement.html(result.data).show(); // tried with element.html() (the same output)
                    RecursionHelper.compile(element, function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) { });
                });
            });
        },
        controller: 'ActivityListCtrl'
    };
});
```

I expect that html file (e.g. answer.singleline.html):

```
{{question.Description}}
```

to display my question description instead of returning the output as a string / text ( {{question.Description}} )

Comment: I'm also working on dynamic templates and have a [partially working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MTDwuY8l2bdFVZ8iJOsb?p=preview) ([method binding doesn't work yet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27939537/1847187)), maybe it will give you some hints.