# AngularJS Dynamic Directives and Method Binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create an AngularJS version of the Bootstrap Panel to learn about dynamic directives. So far I've created a directive where you can insert arbitrary other directives, in example:

```
  <panel panel-model="panel" toggle-collapse="toogleCollapse">
    <panel-body>
      <some-other-directive display-text="panel.content" ></some-other-directive>
    </panel-body>
  </panel>
```

The panel directive has an isolated scope, that's why I'm passing the toggleCollapse function to the directive. Inside the panel template the function should be invoked via ng-click, but this never happens. Any hints are appreciated!

Regards,
Andi

There's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BDSsXy?p=preview) to illustrate the problem.

[Update] Problem solved and plunk updated.

Comment: As you are passing a function it should be : `toggle-collapse="toogleCollapse()"`

Comment: I don't see where is your toogleCollapse function definition ?

Comment: @Cétia It's in the PanelCtrl controller.

Comment: You should consider summarizing what you did to solve the problem and post it as an answer.